# Getting multiple attachments to email in both Mail and Gmail with Android

Tags: android

I can get both Mail and Gmail to attach multiple csv files to an email.

When sent via Mail **all** the attachments are delivered.
When sent by Gmail **none** of the attachments are delivered.

I have read the documentation [Send Binary Content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content).  I have searched but only found a solution for Gmail that does not work with Mail.  Mail seems happy with just about any approach.  Gmail just doesn't want to play.

Has anyone found a solution for sending multiple attachments that works with both Mail and Gmail?

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
String subject = context.getString(R.string.export_data_email_header);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.setType("text/csv");

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
if (diariesSelected) uris.add(Uri.fromFile(context.getFileStreamPath("diaries.csv")));
...
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

And the code used to create the file

```
 FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(path, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
 writer.append(builder.toString());
 writer.close();
 fos.close();
```

Comment: hey have you solve this problem?

Comment: @Sanket Have not found an answer, currently sitting in the too-hard basket.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a snippet from one of my apps. As far as I remember, it works with GMail and Mail (Can't verify it at the moment.). It looks basically like your solution, but with a few little differences. Maybe one of them is what you are looking for. :)

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "address@mail.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The actual message");

ArrayList<Uri> attachmentUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for (File attachment : attachments) {
    attachmentUris.add(Uri.fromFile(attachment));
}

emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachmentUris);

startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks forgemo but no luck.  I tried moving the setType method up and changing it to text/plain.  Interested in how you are creating your files if indeed this code does work with Gmail

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get detail information https://stackoverflow.com/a/18225100/942224

by using below code i am attaching image file in gmail or Mail.... hope it will help you

```
Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        ei.setType("plain/text");
        ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email id"});
        ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "That one works");

        ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/certi/qualifications.jpg");
        fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/certi/certificate.jpg");
        fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/Aa.pdf");

        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's

        for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
        {
            File fileIn = new File(fileList.get(i));
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }

        ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ei, "Sending multiple attachment"), 12345);
```

Comment: Thanks Sanket but I need to send multiple attachments, this solution only enables me to send a single attachment.  The description explains this but I've improved the title so it's now clear.  I need to send multiple documents.