# Attach multiple files to EMail from SD Card

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments, android-sdcard

By using following code, i am trying to attach multiple files to an **E-Mail**, but not getting attachments when using `ArrayList`.

```
public void sendImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
            "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "test@domain.tld" });
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    String[] filePaths = new String[] {
            "file:///sdcard/Custom/CapturedVideo.mp4",
            "file:///sdcard/Custom/CapturedImage.jpg" };
    for (String file : filePaths) {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**Note:-**  Earlier i was attaching single file to an EMail ***! successfully !***

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Custom/CapturedImage.jpg"));
```

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18225100/942224

Comment: @InnocentKiller bro need to sort out this ASAP, do something

Comment: @SanketKachhela please post as answer, your code correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with full path like this

```
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/certi/qualifications.jpg")));
```

use this

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
```

instead of

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

try this

```
 Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            ei.setType("plain/text");
            ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email id"});
            ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "That one works");

            ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
            fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/certi/qualifications.jpg");
            fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/certi/certificate.jpg");
            fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/Aa.pdf");

            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's

            for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
            {
                File fileIn = new File(fileList.get(i));
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                uris.add(u);
            }

            ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ei, "Sending multiple attachment"), 12345);
```

Comment: I accepted and ticked as useful here and there both :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one,

```
public void sendImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
"com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "test@domain.tld" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Custom/CapturedVideo.mp4");
fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Custom/CapturedImage.jpg");

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's

for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
    {
 File fileIn = new File(fileList.get(i));
 Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
     uris.add(u);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Just replace your array code with this one and let me know whether it is working or not...